# Twilight times in addition to sunrise/sunset?

Tags: time-date, calendar

The `sunrise-sunset` function from `solar.el` computes sunrise and sunset. I would also like to have a function that computes the end/beginning of

1. civil twilight (center of sun 6 deg below horizon)
2. nautical twilight (center of sun 12 deg below horizon)
3. astronomical twilight (center of sun 18 deg below horizon)

Does anyone know of elisp-code (or a package) for computing said times?

Edit: There seem to be a solution within `solar.el`: The function `solar-sunrise-sunset` calls the function `solar-sunrise-and-sunset` with a HEIGHT of -0.61 degrees (half the apparent diameter of the sun). Using a HEIGHT of -6 degrees should give the end/beginning of civil twilight, and similar for the other.